# Unable to read data from Nordic Power Profiler Kit 2 every millisecond

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have a Nordic Power Profiler connected to a system, I want to get data every millisecond and save it to a CSV file. There is a Power Profiler App as part of the nRF Connect Suite and that works well. But I need to do it in the background without a GUI. So I found an unofficial Python API here: https://github.com/IRNAS/ppk2-api-python

I am using it like this:

```
import time
from ppk2_api.ppk2_api import PPK2_API


ppk2_test = PPK2_API("COM7")
ppk2_test.get_modifiers()
ppk2_test.set_source_voltage(2900)

ppk2_test.use_ampere_meter()  # set ampere meter mode
ppk2_test.toggle_DUT_power("ON")  # enable DUT power

ppk2_test.start_measuring()
for i in range(0, 1000):
    read_data = ppk2_test.get_data()
    if read_data != b'':
        samples, raw_digital = ppk2_test.get_samples(read_data)
        print(f"Average of {len(samples)} samples is: {sum(samples)/len(samples)}uA")

    time.sleep(0.001)  # lower time between sampling -> less samples read in one sampling period

ppk2_test.stop_measuring()
```

The problem I am facing is that no matter how much I reduce the time.sleep(), it always reads 1024 samples. I also, put a timestamp in the get_samples function so I can see how fast the data is being returned but it is every 10ms. If I average that data then I am getting data too slow and missing lots of information.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get data reliably every 1ms